# Fixed timestep gives alternating ticks per second

Tags: javascript, frame-rate, game-loop

So I've read the famous article at http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/comment-page-2/#comments which describes different methods of implementing a game loop. I've tried to implement the final method that is described in the article in Javascript (ignoring interpolation for the time being):

```
var Timer = {
        pastTime : 0,
        currentTime : 0,
        started : false,
        //starts the timer
        start: function(){
            if(!this.started){
                this.started = true;
                this.pastTime = new Date().getTime();
            }
        },
        //gets the time in MILLSECONDS
        getTime: function(){
            return new Date().getTime() - this.pastTime;
        },
        //stops the timer but does not reset it (i.e. getTime() can still be     
          called to get the time between start() and end())
        end: function(){
            if(this.started){
                this.currentTime = new Date().getTime();
                this.started = false;
                return this.currentTime - this.pastTime;
            }
        },
        //resets the timer
        reset: function(){
            this.pastTime = 0;
            this.currentTime = 0;
            this.started = false;
}

var maxFrameSkip = 5;
var nextTick = new Date().getTime();
var TICKS_PER_SECOND = 25;
var tickTimeMillis = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;

var ticksPerSecondReal = 0;
var ticksCounter = 0;

var timer = Object.create(Timer);

var loops = 0;

function gameLoop(){         
        loops = 0;          

        timer.start(); 

        while(new Date().getTime() > nextTick && loops < maxFrameSkip){
            update();  
            ticksCounter++;
            nextTick += tickTimeMillis;
            loops++;
        }

        draw();      

        if(timer.getTime() >= 1000){
            ticksPerSecondReal = ticksCounter;
            ticksCounter = 0;
            timer.reset();
        } 

        console.log(ticksPerSecondReal);   

        window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
    }

gameLoop();
```

So the problem that I'm having is that the console.log(ticksPerSecondReal) should always be giving me 25 because that's the constant ticks per second that I want and have set up. What I end up getting is an alternating number that is 25 and 26. So periodically (~1 second) it will be 25 and then 26 and then 25 and so on. It keeps switching back and forth when it should be constant at 25. What is the issue here?

Comment: Is it altering every second between 25 and 26 in a pattern, or just randomly?

Comment: Still reading through the code, but you might want to use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`, it should be slightly more performant.

Comment: @BoltKey it's kind of in a pattern... like the pattern might switch here and there.

Comment: The real fps updates exactly once every second, you do understand that right?

Comment: Where is the *update* function?

Comment: It's not relevant because they don't do anything atm. The issue doesn't have to do with what's inside the draw or update functions, it has to do with the game loop overall.